# error: curl: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)

Tags: curl, tcl, libcurl

Hello i have this error when i run curl from tcl error: curl:
   /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)

```
curl --version
curl 7.40.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.40.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

```
root@lasdf :/usr/local/lib$ ll
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    4096 Feb  4 17:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root    4096 Aug  2  2014 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  878996 Feb  4 17:33 libcurl.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     979 Feb  4 17:33 libcurl.la*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Feb  4 17:33 libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.3.0*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      16 Feb  4 17:33 libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  472203 Feb  4 17:33 libcurl.so.4.3.0*
```

Comment: This implies that you're using a mismatched `curl` and `libcurl`. e.g. `curl` installed by your package manager and `libcurl` compiled yourself.

Answer (score 95):

I also had a problem with `libcurl.so.4: no version information available` in installing CMAKE. I type `cmake`, the output is:

```
cmake: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available     (required by cmake)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
```

I solved this by doing the following:

First, I locate the path of `libcurl.so.4`:

```
locate libcurl.so.4
```

the result is:

```
/home/chenjian/software/curl-7.20.0/lib/.libs/libcurl.so.4
/home/chenjian/software/curl-7.20.0/lib/.libs/libcurl.so.4.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.2.0
```

Second, find the link of libcurl.so.4,type:

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
```

the result:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Aug 16 21:15 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.2.0
```

Third, remove it and rebuild the link to `libcurl.so.4.3.0`:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
```

Next, check it:

```
 ls -l /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
```

well, the output is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Aug 24 09:23 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0
```

Then, I type `cmake -version`, and the result is

```
cmake version 3.2.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

After fixing the bug, I think it may be caused by multi-version of curl, like me, the origin ubuntu environment had one, but I install another one.

Comment: why is this answer below the other one?

Comment: Great Answer! A correction: In `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4`, `-rf` is not needed.

Comment: This resolves my issue, but I'm curious the problem always gets back after a while on my Ubuntu 18.04 system.

Comment: @haxpor I am facing similar issue, did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: @Krishnaraj I'm not sure what happens but I've moved on to 19.10 and I didn't see any problem now.

Comment: This has to be the single most helpful answer I've ever come across on stackoverflow. Solved so many similar issues, i.e. `libstdc++.so.6 'GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found`, `libuuid.so.1 no version information`, and many more. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

I encountered this problem while building a newer version of curl 7.5.61 and then rebuilding my application. The solution for me was to set the `--enable-versioned-symbols` which is disabled by default.

```
./configure --enable-versioned-symbols
```

Comment: You should really remove that --prefix. It could really mess someone up if PWD is for example in their home directory.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the suggestion on enabled-versioned-symbols. I was building from source and didn't realize I was just not configuring it right at the install. This really helped a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

In my ubuntu 16.04, I came across the same problem when I export anaconda bin to `PATH` and lib to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I solved it by installing cmake from conda-forge: `conda install cmake`. If you use anaconda as me, you can use this method to fix it, otherwise use others' solutions.

Answer (score 4):

On my Ubuntu 12.04 system, this error was emitted when running `/usr/bin/curl` (from the `curl` installable package) when there was a `/usr/local/bin/curl` in place already.  Do a `which curl` and see which one is executing -- if it's `/usr/bin/curl`, try executing `/usr/local/bin/curl` instead.

I ran into this in the context of crontab, which runs with a different path from my user.  The quick fix was to specify my `curl`s explicitly with `/usr/local/bin/curl`

Comment: Thanks, had this same issue. I went ahead and `apt-get remove curl` which removed /usr/bin/curl (version 7.35) and then linked it to my /usr/local/bin/curl (version 7.46) with `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/curl /usr/bin/curl`.

Answer (score 2):

On the latest ubuntu (18.4) I had to
`sudo apt-get remove libcurl.`
and then reinstall what is needed, e.g., `curl`

Comment: After removing the existing libcurl
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As to me, my system is ubuntu16 having a default curl. But I install a curl by source code.

```
root@xy:~/cmake_practice/cmake_build/build_demo9# locate libcurl.so.4
/home/xy/anaconda2/lib/libcurl.so.4
/home/xy/anaconda2/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0
/home/xy/anaconda2/pkgs/curl-7.55.1-hcb0b314_2/lib/libcurl.so.4
/home/xy/anaconda2/pkgs/curl-7.55.1-hcb0b314_2/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.4.0
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0
```

Then i see the new libcurl.so I install recently(May 20 19:54):

```
root@xy:~/cmake_practice/cmake_build/build_demo9# ll -th /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 May 20 19:54 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.4.0*
```

And then i rm them:

```
root@xy:~/cmake_practice/cmake_build/build_demo9# rm -f /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
root@xy:~/cmake_practice/cmake_build/build_demo9# rm -f /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0
```

check it:

```
root@xy:~/cmake_practice/cmake_build/build_demo9# cmake --version
cmake version 3.5.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
root@xy:~/cmake_practice/cmake_build/build_demo9#
```

Answer (score 0):

here I have a simple solution.

You may installed libcurl and ran into the issue.
But you can solve it by merely rebuilding your own cmake with the libcurl you installed (use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to your libcurl)

Works for me. (Ubuntu 16.04, libcurl 4.5 and cmake 3.11.3)